# How can I change x2go's keyboard shortcut bindings on OS X?

Tags: macos

x2go has [Control-Option-F as a keyboard shortcut for "fullscreen"](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/doc:usage:x2goclient#keyboard_shortcuts).  This gets in the way of emacs's `forward-sexp` binding.  How can I disable x2go's shortcut bindings?  As suggested by [these instructions](http://wiki.x2go.org/doku.php/wiki:advanced:nx-keyboard-shortcuts), I have tried putting a file at `~/.x2go/config/keystrokes.cfg` with the following contents:

`<!DOCTYPE NXKeystroke>
<keystrokes>
</keystrokes>`

However, Control-Option-F still results in toggling fullscreen.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to Ionic on the #x2go IRC channel, I put the same contents in /etc/x2go/keystrokes.cfg, and now the fullscreen binding is disabled.

Curious  about why I had to change a server-side config to change this client-side behavior, but I'm happy now.

Thanks, Ionic!